# Regular expression for Curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text containing that kind of structure

```
Any words that should be excluded {UH#sentence A*sentence B*sentence C} {UH#sentence D*sentence E*sentence F}  {UH#sentence G*sentence H} any other
```

I try to have a match for

**Group 0**: UH

**Group 1**: sentence A

**Group 2**: sentence B

**Group 3**: sentence C

So I have a regex like this which is working

```
\{(\w*[^i])#(^$|.+?)\*(^$|.+?)\*(^$|.+?)}\g
```

But this regex also match for structure with only one "*" if their is multiple of them. In the following exemple, group 3 is matching when he shouldn't.

```
Any words that should be exclued {UH#sentence G*sentence H} excluded {UH#sentence A*sentence B dzqd*sentence C} {UH#sentence D*sentence E*sentence F}   any other
```

**Group 3**: sentence H} excluded {UH#sentence A

A link for the demonstration https://regex101.com/r/QQASlJ/1/.
The regex are going to be used in javascript.

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. First match the bracketed strings. Then split the inside of that into groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might so it by first matching the format of the strings and use 2 capture groups.

```
{(\w+)#([^{}]+)}
```

The pattern matches:

- `{` Match opening curly
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `#` Match literally
- `([^{}]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ any char except for `{` and `}`
- `}` Match closing curly

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WZj7xt/1)

Then you could process the capture groups in a second step, where you could split group 2 on `*`

```js
const s = "Any words that should be excluded {UH#sentence A*sentence B*sentence C} {UH#sentence D*sentence E*sentence F}  {UH#sentence G*sentence H} any other";
const regex = /{(\w+)#([^{}]+)}/g;
const result = Array.from(
  s.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1]].concat(m[2].split(/\s*\*/))
);
console.log(result);
```

---

As you are using Javascript, another option could be using an infinite width lookbehind [if supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind). It does not give the separate group values, but only the matches.

```
(?<={(?:\w+#[^{}]*)?)[^{}*#]+(?=[^{}]*})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IXg9zn/1)

```js
const s = "Any words that should be excluded {UH#sentence A*sentence B*sentence C} {UH#sentence D*sentence E*sentence F}  {UH#sentence G*sentence H} any other";
const regex = /(?<={(?:\w+#[^{}]*)?)[^{}*#]+(?=[^{}]*})/g;
const result = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[0]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Have what you don't want in the RegEx**

You are using `.+?` (isn't this the same as `.*`), which also matches the curly brackets `}`.

You could say "all characters but closing curly brackets" `[^}]*`:

```
{(\w*[^i])#(^$|[^}]*)\*(^$|[^}]*)\*(^$|[^}]*)}
```

This works with your examples given.